# Importing pyplot in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Running Python 2.7 and trying to get plotting to work the tutorials recommend the below command.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Works fine when run from the command line

```
python -c "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt"
```

but I get an error when trying to run it inside a Jupyter Notebook.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-1d1446f6fa64> in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
    112 
    113 from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
--> 114 _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
    115 
    116 _IP_REGISTERED = None

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.pyc in pylab_setup()
     30     # imports. 0 means only perform absolute imports.
     31     backend_mod = __import__(backend_name,
---> 32                              globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
     33 
     34     # Things we pull in from all backends

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/pylab/backend_inline.py in <module>()
    154         configure_inline_support(ip, backend)
    155 
--> 156 _enable_matplotlib_integration()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/pylab/backend_inline.py in _enable_matplotlib_integration()
    152     backend = get_backend()
    153     if ip and backend == 'module://%s' % __name__:
--> 154         configure_inline_support(ip, backend)
    155 
    156 _enable_matplotlib_integration()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in configure_inline_support(shell, backend)
    359     except ImportError:
    360         return
--> 361     from matplotlib import pyplot
    362 
    363     cfg = InlineBackend.instance(parent=shell)

ImportError: cannot import name pyplot
```

The following command works

```
import matplotlib
```

But the following gives me a similar error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the `%matplotlib inline` magic, but it has to be preceded by the pure `%matplotlib` line:

**Works (figures in new window)**

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Works (inline figures)**

```
%matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Does not work**

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Also: [Failure to import matplotlib.pyplot in jupyter (but not ipython)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838914/failure-to-import-matplotlib-pyplot-in-jupyter-but-not-ipython) seems to be the same issue. It looks like a recently introduced bug in the ipykernel. Maybe someone mark this or the other question as duplicate, thx.